# How to test an input so that I can view the output with real data

Tags: python, list, nested

I'm wanting to test an input of data so that I can see what the output looks like, to check where things might be going wrong / doing what I don't want them to be doing.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())

    # create empty list for students and then add the names and scores
    students = []
    students.append([name, score])
    
    lowest_score = min(students, key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(lowest_score)`
```

I want to be able to view the output of lowest_score and want to inset input() dummy data:

```
3
Alice
85.6
Bob
77.3
Charlie
92.1
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to move the list above the loop and unindent the min and print so it only occurs once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# create empty list for students
students = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input()) 
    students.append([name, score])

lowest_score = min(students, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(lowest_score)
```

dummy input:

```
3
Alice
85.6
Bob
77.3
Charlie
92.1
```

output:

```
['Bob', 77.3]
```